# What does internal sparking in a motor mean?

Tags: arduino, motor, raspberry-pi, battery

My Arduino + Raspberry Pi robot was working fine in the morning. I tested it, it ran perfectly, and then I switched it off.

Now in the evening when I'm trying to run it again, with the same batteries and everything, it just doesn't move!

I stripped it down to the motor compartment and found that when I try to run my main motor, I can see sparks through the translucent plastic on the back.

Does that mean my motor is gone?

Comment: To clarify - when you see sparks on the motor, can you say if the motor is **actually** running on its own? (Arcing in the motor is quite common, so if the motor's working there may be some fault elsewhere in the electronics or loose wiring.)

Comment: @Andy yes ofc the motor is running on its own. I'm controlling it the very same way my robot does. I just removed all the wheels and gears and stuff. Wiring shouldn't be loose, all the connections are soldered

Comment: Hmmm next I would check the controller itself, if you have a meter see if there's any voltage at the motor driver's output terminals (when giving stop/start commands). If not, see if anything's coming out of the controller (that is, whatever feeds the motor driver). Don't panic, it  can take a while to trace these sorts of odd random faults...

Comment: @Andy at this point of time I'm pretty convinced that my motor is gone. My  motor driver is perfectly fine. And I can get the motor to work by giving it a bit of push, but its performance is nowhere near the power I used to get. What I am amazed about is how did it short? I mean I've been running it on the same battery, (11.1 V 3300 mAh 25 C LiPo), it works fine in the morning, and when I use the same setup several hours later, the motor just dies.

Comment: Ah if you're sure it's the motor then ignore what I said about the controller :(  I once burned out a motor (in a slot car - don't ask) and it was due to overloading the car. But the failure was obvious at the time - it started to lose speed rapidly. The windings were permanently damaged by excessive heat. But unless you noticed your motor doing the same thing, there must be some other cause...

Comment: @Andy Strange thing is, the motor performed under the same conditions in the morning very well and then failed without making any changes. One thing though, when I tried running it in the evening, the Arduino IDE somehow couldn't detect the serial port. I brought it back home, connected it to my TV and the Arduino worked fine, however I noticed that the wheels were kind of locked. I applied a little bit of force to them and they started moving again (with a bit of friction), and then I came to know of the motor problem. Any guesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a brushed DC motor, then (hopefully) the sparks that you are seeing are a discharge between the commuter and the brushes--this is normal. Another example of this is evident in certain electric drills; under low lighting, you can see sparks through the ventilation holes. If you are interested in this, you can ask at the EE Stack Exchange, or you can grab a textbook.

As for debugging your motor, try using a different voltage supply or use a multi-meter to make sure that your battery is charged. Motors do burn out, and this may have happened, but you should check the easy things first.

**EDIT:**

I found a resource that corroborates what I am suggesting: [Debugging 3-Phase Motor Failure](http://www.pcbheaven.com/userpages/check_the_windings_of_a_3phase_ac_motor/). Your motor is not 3-Phase, but the same idea applies. Measure the winding resistance with a multi-meter. If your coil has broken internally, you will get a very large resistance (unlikely because you are seeing sparks); if you get a very small resistance, smaller than the rated value, then your coil is shorted, which might explain the sparks.

I would do these checks first, then move onto the rest of your components, but if the motor is not spinning under a verified supply voltage, it's definitely toast.

Comment: Batteries are up and running just fine. It's only the motor. I also noticed that the speed of the motor keeps changing randomly. Burned out maybe?

Comment: It may be that the brushes are worn.  If the motor has replaceable brushes you could try that.  Worn brushes could increase the arcing you are observing.

Comment: @SteveO Can't open the motor. Its all in a metal cylinder

Comment: @YaddyVirus Is it an old motor?

Comment: @NBCKLY Nope, It was fitted in a RC car which I bought as the chassis of my robot. It hardly is 20 days old (like from the time I bought it)

Comment: See my edit; it should clarify what you should do.

Comment: @YaddyVirus - I would just an an asterisk ( * ) to NBCKLY's comment, "If the motor is not spinning gunder a **verified supply voltage**, it's definitely toast." The key point there is *verified* supply voltage. An almost-dead battery may read near-rated voltage when no load is applied. Try using fresh/known good batteries or a wall adapter before you discard the motor. The winding check is valid regardless, but you should expect some very low resistance, on the order of tenths to a few Ohms, if the motor's good. It generally needs to be *shorted* to be bad.

Comment: I'm using a 11.1V 3300 mAh 25C LiPo battery. And that's fully charged